# Adding curved shape to box with seamless shading?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shadows, proportional-editing

Suppose I have an empty box, and I want to add a bowl shaped surface starting partway down. See the image below, showing cross section of the box and the annotation depicting what the bowl shape should be like.

[image: cross section]

The precise curve of the bowl shape does not matter, the goal is to make the curved shape fit as well as possibly with the straight wall (in terms of shading). For example, by connecting bridge loops, we can create a shape inside that's sloping downward, but the shape is not steep enough near the box walls to create good shading. See image below (Ignore the sharp angles on the diagonals, which is probably due to bridging a circle with a square. I should have used a better example.)

[image: bridged edge loops]

The angle between the straight box wall and the inner shape is too large, I want to smooth it out. By adding loop cuts to the sloping inner shape, I can manually drag the loops to make the curve steep enough near the wall, but this is extremely imprecise and not nearly good enough.

**Note:** for the simple example provided here, we can fix this problem by starting over with better technique (for example, use a cube then make a boolean cut using some surface). I am interested in ways of actually adding the new shape into the existing mesh as shown above, in cases where restarting is not possible.

Comment: Please consider a  tutorial with topic of proportional editing.  You can find that here on BSE .. perhaps.  Certainly you can find one on the famous video website that has a name that rhymes with NooNoob.  Make sure to have many vertices so that the mesh can be shaped with fluid contours

Comment: Restarting is always possible.

Comment: Hello, please add a wireframe view of your mesh or share your file, without it we can only guess how it works

Comment: You should get what you want with Bridge Edge Loops, no? If it's not exactly the profile you want then give it some corrections with Proportional Editing on